# How to avoid printing commented out code in for loop

Tags: python, printing

If I run this loop, `A` will print 10 times.

```
for i in range(10):
   """
   A
   """
   pass
```

How do I stop this?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how your'e running this but it definitely does not print "A" 10 times.

Comment: @Aplet123 It does, I attached a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't print A at all. Please check your code. You might want to use #A instead of """ if you are trying to pass A as a comment though.

Comment: That's because of the REPL's behavior.

Comment: @Aplet123 Ok so is there any way to stop that from happening, without using # comments since I have a multi-line comment while I'm working with this code? I'm using the default Python interpreter for Windows gotten off the official site.

Comment: The REPL is just for debugging, it's not how scripts are normally executed. Ignore this behavior.

Comment: Much to my surprise, ABC is correct.  I was also convinced it wouldn't do anything!  You can see it more clearly in the one-liner:  `for i in range(10): "hello"`.  

To fix your problem?  Put your code inside a function, and then call the function.  You won't then get the REPL behavior.

Comment: @FrankYellin Thank you, it must be a bug in the REPL.

Comment: @ABC it's not a bug; it's the REPL showing `repr()` for any object that you give it, which is intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code in the python idle shell and got the same output. But when i run it in a file it stops printing this. So **try running it in a file**, not in command prompt or the idle shell

Comment: As mentioned in comments, it's a REPL feature, annoying as though it is.